# Border-width for creating bend border

Tags: html, css

This is about 2 hours that i'm struggling with this site to know how can i create a section like [this website](http://parasponsive.com/para1/)
with border-width not with image ?
something like this :

[image]
when i add `border-width:2000px;`
 i get scroll in bellow the site .

```
    .shape-sormei {
    padding: 30px 0;
    border-right-width: 1366px;
    border-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) #133747 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    border-style: solid dashed solid solid;

}
.bot_box{
    border-style: solid dashed solid solid;
    border-width: 0 2880px 60px 0;
    height: 0;
    width: 0;
}
```

any soloution ?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do and do you have any code to show?

Comment: It would be helpful if we could also see some html (maybe in a jsfiddle). But off the top of my head, have you tried having it's parent have `width: 100%; overflow:hidden;` ?

Comment: Yes , you're right , but problem is javascript , when windows get wide javascript handle it .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### CSS3 (modern browsers)

**[jsBin demo](http://jsbin.com/hebaz/5/edit)**

To calculate the border width instead of javascript you can do it with the
**new CSS3 unit** `vw` **(Viewport Width).**

[image]

```
  <div class="border top"></div>
  <div class="content">
    <h1>Content</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="border bottom"></div>
```

```
.border{
    border-width: 0 100vw 60px 0; /* Or use:  0 0 60px 100vw  to invert! */
    border-style: solid dashed;
}
.border.top{    border-color: #D44032 transparent; }
.border.bottom{ border-color: transparent #D44032; }
```

<sub>Note from the above that if you want to support **old browsers** some **JS to get the document width** will be necessary.</sub>

---

### With JS:

To make it compatible with older browsers here's an example that uses jQuery
to get the right border width:

**[jsBin DEMO with jQuery](http://jsbin.com/hebaz/10/edit)**

```
jQuery(function( $ ){

  var $bord = $('.border');
  function setBordersWidth(){
    $bord.css("border-right-width", $(window).width() );
  }
  setBordersWidth(); // on DOM ready
  $(window).resize(setBordersWidth); // and on resize

});
```

CSS (note I removed the `vw`)

```
.border{
    border-width: 0 0 60px 0; /* Or use: 0 0 60px 0   to invert! */
    border-style: solid dashed;
}
.border.top{    border-color: #D44032 transparent; }
.border.bottom{ border-color: transparent #D44032; }
```

Comment: C. Bulijan great , i didnt know about viewport width .  
but the scroll is still alive :)

Comment: @user3642164 If the scroll is still alive that's probably cause you did NOT removed the margin from `body` that the browser adds by default. (As you can see in my example there's no scrollbars) you need to use a `CSS reset` style (Google for it) or do like: `body{margin:0;}` simply use `*{margin:0; padding:0;}`

Comment: body{margin:0;} *{margin:0; padding:0;} didnt work , i think ishould use reset.css

Comment: @user3642164 use it. As you can see I have no scrollbars. Some usual mistake could also be that you have somewhere some elements set to width 100% but also having left and right margins or paddings. Remove those extras. Edited my answer with a JS example.

Comment: Hey man you're perfect , you made it .  
i disappear the scroll with body{overflow-x:hidden;}  
THX a millon

Comment: @user3642164 glad we did it!! woohooo (note that overflow-x: hidden; in your case is just an ugly fix... you should review all your elements and find the intruder which adds the extra space!)

Comment: sure i'm gonna do this .  
Again Thank You ;)

Answer (score 2):

They use an empty element before:

```
<div class="about_us_top top_box" style="border-left-width: 1280px;"></div>
```

And style it like this:

```css
.top_box {
    border-style: solid solid solid dashed;
    border-width: 60px 0 0 2880px;
}
.about_us_top {
    border-color: transparent transparent transparent #d44032;
}
.top_box, .bot_box {
    height: 0;
    width: 0;
}
```

The inline style `border-left-width: 1280px;` changes with javascript when window is resized.

Comment: Yes and thx for your answer but when i add these code to my css i get scroll below the site !!!

Comment: do you know what the javascript is ?

Answer (score 1):

try this  **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/modaloda/PU4v7/)**

```
<div class="serv_top top_box" style="border-left-width: 1280px;">df</div>
```

CSS

```
body{
   overflow-x: hidden;
}
.serv_top, .top_box{
border-width: 0 0 60px 2880px;
border-style: solid solid solid dashed;
border-color: transparent transparent #FF9900 transparent;
width:100%;
}
```

Comment: javascript for what ?

Comment: i put this code to my css and i get scroll below my site

Comment: The inline style border-left-width: 1280px; changes with javascript when window is resized.

Comment: Just use body{ overflow-x: hidden; }